# Piping output from get-childitem to robocopy

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, robocopy

I have an array of files that need to be moved to a backup locations. I am collecting the array of desired items using a get-childitem command. I am looking to use robocopy to move stuff once the list of collected items is ready.

```
$paths=@()

$srcitems = get-childitem $paths 

robocopy $srcitems $dest /move
```

Does this work?
If not what is the best way to pipe to each individual item to robocopy?

Thanks
Steeluser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
           Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination [file [file]...] [options]

         source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
    destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
           file :: File(s) to copy  (names/wildcards: default is "*.*").
```

Robocopy is expecting a source directory, a destination directory, and a file spec as arguments.  It's difficult to give a definitive answer without knowing what your "list of collected items" looks like.  If it's source directories, then you can foreach that list through a an ivocation of robocopy, and hardcode a wildcard spec for the file names.  If you've got a list of files, you'll need to split those off into directory/file (I'd use split-path), and do an invocation of robocopy for each source directory, specifying the list of files in that directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot mjolinor, your suggestion has helped me create a good working script for my work.

Answer (score 2):

Similar scenario, posting in case it helps:

I needed to copy (move) some folders all beginning with "Friday" and items within from a source to a destination, and came up with this that seems to be working:

```
Get-ChildItem T:\ParentFolder -Filter "Friday*" -Name | ForEach-Object { robocopy "T:\ParentFolder\$_" "E:\$_" /z /s /MOVE }
```

- The "Get-ChildItem" portion lists the folder names (-Name) starting
  with "Friday" (-Filter "Friday*").
- This gets piped to the ForEach-Object where robocopy will execute for every instance found.
- The robocopy /MOVE argument obviously moves the folders/files.

I'm fairly new to Powershell; not sure if there is a better way. The script is still running, but so far so good.

@walid2mi uses Move-Item which I'm sure works; I just like robocopy b/c it has a restartable mode (/Z).

Answer (score 1):

Syntax that worked for me:

```
$srcPath = "C:\somefolder"
$dstPath = "C:\someOtherFolder"
$srcitems = get-childitem $srcPath #whatever condition

$srcitems | Select Name | ForEach-Object {robocopy $srcPath $dstPath $_.name}
```

(which is obvious according to the robocopy documentation)

Answer (score -1):

[robocopy](http://thepowershellguy.com/blogs/posh/archive/tags/robocopy/default.aspx)

```
Get-ChildItem $paths | Move-Item -Destination $dest  -WhatIf
```